# What's the meaning of 'and by' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of 'and by' in this sentence?

> They seemed to be doing all right, **and by,** it must be lovely just to sit back and glide around the bend in the river with the steep wooded bank to one side and the cathedral towering over the water.

This is from 'A Daughter's Duty by Maggie Hope.

Comment: You omitted "be" in _to **be** doing all right_. It helps to say from where the quote is and provide the link.

Comment: It's fron a fiction book by Maggie Hope.

Comment: Include the title and the author in the question, not as a comment. Find the link with this book and insert it in the question as well.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Is there a missing 'by'?  It reads to me as if it were meant to be 'by and by'.

Comment: I believe Graybeard's answer is correct, but, for the sake of others, you should 1. provide several sentences appearing before the one with the phrase in question, and 2. do the same for the *other* appearance of the same phrase in the book: *Ninefields, it was called, though it was surrounded by houses, but Rose supposed that when it was built by an ironmaster of long ago, it had been surrounded by fields. Marina had told her that Elgar* [a famous composer] *had stayed there often, being a friend of the ironmaster, **and by,** she could almost hear his music in the rustle of those trees.*

Comment: Here is how you should quote the first appearance: *‘Have you done this before?’ Marina asked nervously, wishing she hadn’t been so keen to get in the boat. She thought about getting out again, but when she moved the punt rocked alarmingly and Rose, who was just stepping in, shrieked. ‘Keep still, man!’ Marina looked at the punts already on the move. They seemed to be doing all right, **and by,** it must be lovely just to sit back and glide around the bend in the river with the steep wooded bank to one side and the cathedral towering over the water.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will note from the context *that you did not give* that the action takes place in Durham on the River Wear and the characters express themselves in the local dialect.

"and by" is a "minced oath" - a short version of **and by God** - an emphatic or exclamation, in this case, of pleasure or general satisfaction.

From Google Books:

> By St Martins Guisborough Manor Care Home | Facebookhttps://www.facebook.com › ... › Videos
> 17 Dec 2021 — *This morning Guisborough Manor have a visit from the Christmas ballerina Mrs C and by did she put on a show at breakfast.*

> Winning Start To The New Season For Cricketing Ladieshttps://www.hu17.net › 2013/04/24 › winning-start-to-t...
> 24 Apr 2013 — *Louise Todd the team manager and Captain had to bring on a good number of the junior players and by did she pick a good side.*

> TESTIMONIALS - CUBE Design : : Certified Brand Architecthttps://cubedesign.ie › testimonials
> *I handed over complete trust to Barbara to bring my business full circle with its brand strategy and by, did she deliver.* Geraldine O'Brien, Business Owner ...

Comment: They all sound almost like *And Boy!*, too. "Boy, Oh Boy" might then match your minced oath pattern.